# Finding the next and previous word after keyword

Tags: python

I'm looking at  getting the immediate  word before and after a keyword in a  string.

```
text =  "I currently live in Chicago but  work in DC"
keywords = 'live in'
before_keyword, keyword, after_keyword = text.partition(keywords)
print (after_keyword)
```

Output here will be  `Chicago but  work in DC`. before_keyword output  is `I currently`. How can I get only the immediate  term before and after the  keyword? i.e.
`currently` for before_keyword and  `Chicago` in  after_keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `split` to split on whitespace; you can then get the first/last words from each string.

```
>>> text =  "I currently live in Chicago but  work in DC"
>>> keywords = 'live in'
>>> before, _, after = text.partition(keywords)
>>> before.split()[-1]
'currently'
>>> after.split()[0]
'Chicago'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just split the strings by the space character ( ) and get the first/last elements:

```
>>> before_keyword = before_keyword.split()[-1]
>>> after_keyword = after_keyword.split()[0]

>>> before_keyword
'currently'

>>> after_keyword
'Chicago'
```

Answer (score 0):

First, we partition the `text` variable.

Second, we get the last index of `text.partition(keywords)[0]` by using `.split()[-1]`. This will be assigned to the `before` variable.

Third, we get the first index of `text.partition(keywords)[2]` using `.split()[0]` and this will be assigned to the `after` variable.

```
>>> text =  "I currently live in Chicago but  work in DC"
>>> keywords = 'live in'

>>> before = text.partition(keywords)[0].split()[-1]
>>> after = text.partition(keywords)[2].split()[0]

>>> before
'currently'

>>> after
'Chicago'
```